# how to limit a sql trace to a single stored proc?

Tags: sql-server

how can I limit a SQL server trace to only a single stored proc?

I know we can trace db activity then filter results but i want to be efficient in the way the trace is executed, if possible.

Answer (score 1):

it called a [trace filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174404.aspx), you probably only want to do this if you're setting up some kind of system process to grab diagnostic data.

If you are only doing this once you want to use SQL Server Profiler (which uses SQL Trace), you can do this through the Event Selection Tab -> Column Filters -> then click on text data

Comment: When specifying the sproc name in the like field, make sure to specify as %<sproc name>%